# Проблемы с запуском бота vps

Tags: python, ubuntu

Проблемы появляются при запуске bot.py, в логах пишет:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiogram'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/telegram_bot/bot.py", line 4, in <module>
    from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
```

Перед этим я проделал apt апдейт и апгрейд, установил питон 3.11, установил nodejs, npm, pg2.
После перекинул все файлы бота в отдельную директорию, перешёл в неё, произвёл pip install.
Через pg2 запускаю bot.py с выбором интерпритатора python3.11 и модуль не найден. С чем может быть это связано?

Comment: [возможные дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=No+module+named+%27aiogram%27)

Comment: Попробуйте `pip show aiogram`. Если вышла ошибка, значит модуль не установился.